# Doctrine generate code with other naming conventions

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

We are starting with Symfony2 and Doctrine. I need to select some data from tables that already exist. These tables and column names do not use the naming conventions as defined by Doctrine.

I was wondering if I could create my own naming scheme somewhere. Mainly, we use PascalCase table and columnnames, without underscored. This results in Entity properties like $firstpromotiondatetime while the column is FirstPromotionDateTime, so i'd like my property to be firstPromotionDateTime.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily need to use doctrine's entity generator to generate new entities, you can also manually do it.  However, you can also generate the entities via the command line, and then open your entity classes and change the property names as you see fit.  Just make sure that the doctrine mapping (use the following annotation for instance) is still pointing to the correct column name in your database.

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime $firstPromotionDateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="FirstPromotionDateTime", type="datetime")
 */
private $firstPromotionDateTime;
```

**Edit:**

If you manually change the property names, also make sure you have correctly modified the setters & getters as well.

Comment: That was not my question. Of course I can always do everything manually, but I need to create lots of tables with lots of columns. So generating from the cli would be great, but I just want to use our already existing naming conventions for these old database setups.